# rotate entire widget, not only its canvas

Tags: kivy

In this [example](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__canvas__rotation__py.html), we can see a rotation of the canvas. But clicking the button's corners isn't registered. How can I rotate the entire button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on inclement's answer, I've created a button on a scatter layout, which has its *hitbox* set correctly.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
FloatLayout:

    ScatterLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 200
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

        rotation: 45

        do_rotation: False
        do_scale: False
        do_translation: False

        Button:
            text: 'hello world'
'''


class RotationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

RotationApp().run()
```

I used scatter layout instead of scatter, because it passes its size to children widgets. The `do_x: False` aren't needed in this example, because button intercepts touching events, but if I placed a label, it would move on touch.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably override its `collide_point` method to account for the rotation by transforming the touch coordinates.

If you use the widget system (e.g. putting the Button in a Scatter), the collision is taken care of for you.