# Why does the rotated button widget's position doesn't rotate?

Tags: python, kivy

I have two button widgets. The Button1 was rotated and the Button2 wasn't. I'm trying to test if the two button widgets will collide.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.logger import Logger

class RotateMe(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate(angle= 45, origin= self.center)

        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

class Main(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.size = Window.size
        self.rotatethis = RotateMe(text= "Button1", center= self.center)
        self.add_widget(self.rotatethis)

        self.somebutton = Button()
        self.somebutton.text = "Button2"
        self.somebutton.right = self.center_x - 60
        self.somebutton.y = self.center_y
        self.add_widget(self.somebutton)

        if self.somebutton.collide_widget(self.rotatethis):
            Logger.info("The buttons collided! Much happiness") 
        else:
            Logger.info("The buttons didn't collide. Such sadness.")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

TestApp().run()
```

This is how it looked when I ran my code.

[image]

I can clearly see from the output (the image) that the two buttons collided but  when I checked the log , it says that the Button Widgets didn't collide. It seems that the widget position of Button1 didn't change/rotate.

I tried to change the position of the Button2 to see at which point it collides with Button1. And I found out that the Widget position of Button1 didn't change.

Like this:

[image: Buttton image]

The white square at the back of Button1 is the actual position of the Button1 widget.

Is there a way to rotate the position of Button1 widget?

**UPDATE**: I tried to use the ScatterLayout as suggested in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694835/rotate-entire-widget-not-only-its-canvas)

Here is my updated code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class RotateMe(ScatterLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        ScatterLayout.__init__(self)

        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (100, 100)

        self.rotation = 45

        self.do_rotation = False

        self.add_widget(Button(text= "Button1"))

class Main(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.size = Window.size

        self.rotatethis = RotateMe()
        self.rotatethis.center = self.center
        self.add_widget(self.rotatethis)

        self.button2 = Button(text= "Button2")
        self.button2.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.button2.size = (100, 100)
        self.button2.right = self.center_x - 60
        self.button2.y = self.center_y

        self.add_widget(self.button2)



        if self.button2.collide_widget(self.rotatethis):
            Logger.info("The buttons collided! Much happiness") 
        else:
            Logger.info("The buttons didn't collide. Such sadness.")


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

TestApp().run()
```

Now the buttons were collided but when I try to change the position of  the Button2, like this:

```
self.button2.y = self.center_y + 45
```

The output is like this:

[image: The Output]

Looking at the output (image), the two buttons' widgets doesn't seem to collide with each other but when I look at the log, it says that they collided with each other.

It turns out that the widget size of Button1 is this (the colored teal background):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rotate entire widget, not only its canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694835/rotate-entire-widget-not-only-its-canvas)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35694835/1149933.  In short; put the button inside a `Scatter`.